# CDK import of an existing Cloudformation stack. How to find what resource TYPES were used during parsing by CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I've parsed multiple existing Cloudformation stacks into my Java program and am trying now to cast some of the resources in them to the correct Object type, to be able to get their parameters easily. The issue is, I do not want to do this maually. Which means that I would love the possibility to find the class CDK used to parse the JSON with. For whatever reason, I cannot find a method for it except one that is not even described in the CDK. ($jsii$toJson()).

The code I am using:

```
for (CDKStack x : holderForAWSState.getStackList()) {
  Iterator <IConstruct> iter = x.getTemplate().getNode().getChildren().iterator();
  while(iter.hasNext()) {
    IConstruct temp = iter.next();
    System.out.println(temp.$jsii$toJson().toString());
  }
}
```

```
This produces this for one of the stacks: 
{"$jsii.byref":"constructs.Construct@10004"}
{"$jsii.byref":"constructs.Construct@10005"}
{"$jsii.byref":"constructs.Construct@10006"}
{"$jsii.byref":"aws-cdk-lib.aws_logs.CfnLogGroup@10007"}
{"$jsii.byref":"aws-cdk-lib.aws_iam.CfnRole@10008"}
{"$jsii.byref":"aws-cdk-lib.aws_iam.CfnRole@10009"}
{"$jsii.byref":"aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda.CfnFunction@10010"}
{"$jsii.byref":"aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda.CfnVersion@10011"}
{"$jsii.byref":"aws-cdk-lib.aws_apigateway.CfnRestApi@10012"}
{"$jsii.byref":"aws-cdk-lib.aws_apigateway.CfnMethod@10013"}
{"$jsii.byref":"aws-cdk-lib.aws_apigateway.CfnMethod@10014"}
{"$jsii.byref":"aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda.CfnPermission@10015"}
{"$jsii.byref":"aws-cdk-lib.aws_apigateway.CfnDeployment@10016"}
{"$jsii.byref":"aws-cdk-lib.aws_cloudwatch.CfnAlarm@10017"}
{"$jsii.byref":"aws-cdk-lib.aws_cloudwatch.CfnAlarm@10018"}
{"$jsii.byref":"constructs.Construct@10019"}
{"$jsii.byref":"constructs.Construct@10020"}
```

So I could get the type from here with a simple regex. But the thing is I would expect a proper method to get that it is a "CfnRestApi". I would prefer to avoid using something that is described nowhere and could be closed down any second. Does anyone know how to do this without this funny method?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question is:
`temp.getClass()`
as the item is already of the class, but for some reason the way it is written in the example on AWS page made me think otherwise.